# Java GUI button, dialog window and input

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I am trying to make a sort of phonebook and my skills in Java's GUI are rusty as I haven't made one in years. So let's assume for now that I have a single button on my window. When I click it I want it to pop up with a dialog window with three sections to input text (First Name, Last Name, and Phone number) and then when the user clicks the ok button at the bottom it will add these to a list of names and phonenumbers. What code will I need to make the button perform this action? I already know how to make the button so I'm mainly wondering about the action it performs and how to make the dialog window I need.

Answer (score 1):

> and how to make the dialog window I need.

You make a JDialog window the same way you make a JFrame window, somethink like:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add( someComponent );
panel.add( anotherComponent );
JDialog dialgo = new JDialog();
dialog.add(panel);
dialog.pack();
dialog.setVisible( true );
```

Normally this code would be contains in a separate class and you just create an instance of the class in your ActionListener.

Comment: Thank you for this, this is what I was looking for, though now I need to figure out how to get it to return the values in the textfields. Shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so example your button is called button1. You will have to add an ActionListner to that button and an ActionPerformed (Which will encapasulate what happens when the button is clicked.)  When the button is clicked you can create a new panel adding textboxs' in the panel.You can then add another button to proceed, which will have its ActionListner/ActionPerfromed duet storing the string inputed into the textbox into a defined String. Sample code below:

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JTextField textbox = new JTextField(50);
        JTextField textbox1 = new JTextField(50);
        JTextField textbox3 = new JTextField(50);

        label.setText("Please enter Something below on the textbox: ");
        panel1.add(label);
        panel1.add(textbox);
        panel1.add(textbox1);
        panel1.add(textbox2);

        JButton button3 = new JButton();
        button3.setText("CLICK TO PROCEED");
        panel1.add(button3, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        frame.setContentPane(panel1);
        frame.invalidate();
        frame.validate();   

        button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            String s1 = textbox.getText();
            String s2 = textbox1.getText();
            String s3 = textbox2.getText();}}
```

Hope this helps. However, Please note that the variables defined under the actionPerformed are local. s1,s2,s3 cannot be used outside. Better to create private static variables outside the ActionListner/ActionPerformed method.

Comment: So you're saying the variables I put in the dialog box won't be sent back to the main method?